# Checking whether an element exist or not in the map within map

Tags: c++, stl

I have a map of the form `map<key1, map<key2, value> >` **:**

For Example:
I am storing the intensity value at 2-D co-ordinate(x,y) in following map:

```
map<int, map<int, double> > intensityValue;
```

Now, I want to check whether intensity value at co-ordinate (x,y) exist in this map or not.
One way that I know is to check :

```
if(intensityvalue[x][y] >=0)
```

in this case, if `intensityValue[x][y]` does not exist in map then after checking it will automatically insert `intensityValue[x][y]` in the map **which I don't want**.

Please suggest an efficient way, so that I can check whether `intensityValue[x][y]` already exist in the map or not without inserting it in the map.

Comment: [`std::map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`std::map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) together with short-circuit evaluation:

```
bool foundXY = instensityValue.find(x) != intensityValue.end() &&
               intensityValue[x].find(y) != intensityValue[x].end();
```

or [`std::map::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/count):

```
bool foundXY = instensityValue.count(x) && intensityValue[x].count(y)
```

Comment: should probably use `count()` for the y value check.

Comment: @JaredC That is an option. I find `count` a bit counter intuitive for a map since the result can only be 0 or 1, but I will add the option.

Comment: I believe `count` and `find` have the same complexity and should probably have about the same performance? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Yes, same complexity. It is just badly named, since the result is binary, but you don't need to compare with end iterators.

Comment: It isn't badly named. Its name is unified with other containers. So, for example, you can write template code that uses `count` and works with any STL container.

Comment: this is an old thread, but isn't it more efficient to use 'find' to find an element, because 'count' will always go at the end of the map because even though there is one element for the given key can exist, the algorithm will go to the end of the list because that's how a count algo works?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::map::find` and check if the element exists before accessing it. You can read the usage/documentation here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find

Answer (score 1):

Write a short function for it to ensure the minimum number of map finding is called.

```
bool hasIntensity(int x, int y)
{
    map<int, map<int, double> >::const_iterator i = intensityValue.find(x);
    if (i == intensityValue.end()) return false;
    map<int, double>::const_iterator j = i->second.find(y);
    return j != (i->second.end());
}
```

If you want to get the actual value when the element is found, just utilize `j->second`.

Comment: This should probably return the iterator instead of a bool. That way you can actually do something with the found value instead of having to do the map lookups all over again.

Comment: Sure, but the returned iterator should be handled carefully to avoid accessing invalidated iterators.

Comment: @timrau Just like we need to do with iterator returned by `find` :)

Comment: The problem is, what iterator to return? It looks like the iterator which would indicate failure to find something is not of the same type as the one that would point to the found element.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find)

```
auto outerIt = intensityValue.find(x);
if (outerIt != intensityValue.end()) {
    auto innerIt = outerIt->find(y);
    if (innerIt != outerIt->end()) {
        // Do something with the found value
        return;
    }
}
// Didn't return, so it wasn't found
```

That said, in my experience, using a single map of pairs for this kind of thing is more efficient and easier to use than a nested map. It fits better into standard algorithms and doesn't involve nearly as much tree navigation.

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename V>
using map2d = std::map<std::pair<T, U>, V>;

int main() {
    map2d<int, int, double> myMap {
        {{3, 4}, 808.14f},
        {{1, 2}, 333.33f}
    };
    auto it = myMap.find({3, 4});
    if (it != myMap.end()) {
        std::cout << it->second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Cogwheel: I used nested map intentionally because at later stage I need all the points in the row for a particular 'x' value whose intensity value is set i.e. intensityValue[x][*], which will be difficult to find using this method (I think so, not sure) ;)

Comment: outerIt returns a pair. Therefore "outerIt->find(y)" should be "outerIt->second.find(y)"

Answer (score 0):

This is bit ugly but should work too : (using C++11)

```
std::map<int, std::map<int, double> > intensityValue;
int x,y;
auto it = std::find_if(intensityValue.begin(),
                    intensityValue.end(),
                    [x,y](const std::pair<int, std::map<int, double>>& p){
                      return p.first==x && 
                             p.second.find(y) !=p.second.end();
                    }
                    );

  if(it != intensityValue.end())
  {
      //Got it !
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that loses the benefit of the logarithmic complexity of `map::find` and `map::count`.

Comment: @juanchopanza yeah, agreed !